# Rigid body kinetic energy extra term

Tags: dynamical-systems, cross-product

I am looking at the derivation of the kinetic energy of a rigid body, with an initial velocity:

$v = v_{com} + w \times r$

I start with:
 $T = \int \frac12 v \cdot v \  dm=\int \frac12(v_{com} + w \times r) \ \cdot \ (v_{com} + w \times r) \ dm$

and after expanding all terms and substituting known variables I end up with

$T = \frac12M(v_{com} \cdot v_{com})+\frac12 (w \cdot Iw)+Mv_{com} \cdot w \times r $

I was wondering why this last term ends up disappearing since the final solution listed in my textbook is $T = \frac12M(v_{com} \cdot v_{com})+\frac12 (w \cdot Iw) $

Comment: isn't $v_{com}$ perpendicular to $w\times r$? so dot product is zero.

Comment: @Nasser - no, the direction in which an object is headed has no a priori relationship to how the object is spinning.

Comment: @slader - how can you have $r$ in your final expression for $T$? $r$ is the location of the differential element $dm$ being integrated. It is only defined insdie the integration. Once the integration is finished, there is no longer such a thing as $r$.

Answer (score 1):

When you expand $T = \int \frac12(v_{com} + \omega \times r) \ \cdot \ (v_{com} + \omega \times r) \ dm$, you get

$$T = \frac 12 \int v_{com}^2 \,dm + \frac 12 \int \|\omega \times r\|^2\, dm + \int v_{com}\omega \times r\,dm$$

As you've noted, the first two terms simplify to $\frac 12 Mv_{com}^2 + \frac 12(\omega \cdot I\omega)$. But in the last term, $r$ is not constant, so it does not simplify to $Mv_{com}\omega \times r$. And as I said in the comment, $r$ is not even defined outside the integral.

Instead, since $v_{com}$ and $\omega$ are constant, we get
$$\int v_{com}\omega \times r\,dm = v_{com}\omega \times \int r\,dm$$

So the question remains, what is $\int r\,dm$? This can be a little tricky to recognize. $r$ is the location of the differential element $dm$, *relative to the center of mass*. If we fix an arbitrary coordinate system and let $R$ be the position vector, then $r = R - R_{com}$, where $R_{com}$ is the center of mass. So
$$\int r\,dm = \int (R - R_{com})\,dm = \int R\,dm - MR_{com}$$

But the center of mass is defined by $$R_{com} := \frac{\int R\,dm}M$$

So you end up with $$\int r\,dm = 0$$

Comment: perfect, thank you for the explanation